# How to add Multiple conditional Panel in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a shiny app where user will have 2 choices,1. Show states & 2. Show statistics. If user selects show states then it will show a drop down of states & if user select show statistics then it will show list of statistics. I wrote below code

```
library('shiny')
ui=fluidPage(
sidebarPanel(
checkboxInput('cb',"show States",FALSE),
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.cb==true",
  selectInput("Ind","Select Indian State:",
  c("Maharastra"="MH","Karnataka"="KA","West Bengal"="WB"))
),
 checkboxInput("stat","show statistics"),

conditionalPanel(
  condition1="input.stat==TRUE",
  checkboxGroupInput("disp","Select Statistics:",c("Confirmed"="conf","Recovered"="rec","Deceased"="dec"))

)

)
)
server=function(input,output){}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server = server)
```

My first conditional input is working but second one is not working. Can you suggest me the correction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo

```
library('shiny')
ui=fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
        checkboxInput('cb',"show States",FALSE),
        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.cb==true",
            selectInput("Ind","Select Indian State:",
                        c("Maharastra"="MH","Karnataka"="KA","West Bengal"="WB"))
        ),
        checkboxInput("stat","show statistics",FALSE),

        conditionalPanel(
            condition="input.stat==true",
            checkboxGroupInput("disp","Select Statistics:",c("Confirmed"="conf","Recovered"="rec","Deceased"="dec"))

        )

    )
)
server=function(input,output){}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Can you please let me know what was the error?